# Selecting from xml based on attributes in multiple subnodes

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodes>
  <node id="1">
    <subnode name="a" value="1" />
    <subnode name="b" value="2" />
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <subnode name="a" value="2" />
    <subnode name="b" value="2" />
  </node>
  <node id="3">
    <subnode name="a" value="1" />
    <subnode name="b" value="1" />
  </node>
  <node id="4">
    <subnode name="a" value="1" />
    <subnode name="b" value="2" />
  </node>
</nodes>
```

I need to select the id's of the nodes that have both `a=1` and `b=2` (in this case node 1 and node 4).

I would prefer to do it using linq, and I have the following code to select those that have `a=1`. How do I expand the code to also take care of the second requirement?

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\subnodes.xml");

var x = from topnode in document.Descendants("nodes")
   let nodes = topnode.Descendants("node") from n in nodes
   let subnodes = n.Descendants("subnode") from s in subnodes
   where s.Attribute("name").Value == "a" && s.Attribute("value").Value == "1"
   select n.Attribute("id").Value;
```

EDIT: I've made a .NET Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOg3wv

Comment: `where (s.Attribute("name").Value == "a" && s.Attribute("value").Value == "1") && (s.Attribute("name").Value == "b" && s.Attribute("value").Value == "2")`

Comment: @Aarif: Attribute "name"  cannot be both `a` and `b`. This selects no nodes.

Comment: use an `or` condition in this case `||`

Comment: @Aarif: That selects node 2 and 3 as well.

Comment: got it, let me update the query

Comment: how about this one `var x=document.Descendants("nodes").Descendants("node").Descendants("subnode").Where(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "a" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value == "1").Where(a =>a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "b" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value =="2") .Select(a => a.Attribute("id")?.Value).ToList();`

Comment: are you certain there'd only be two elements (subnodes) under the `node` element?

Comment: let me know if this query doesn't work

Comment: @Aarif: There are many subnodes with name-value pairs under each node.

Comment: @Aarif: That query gives me 0 items.

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following.

```
var result = document.Descendants("node").Where(x=>x.Descendants("subnode")
            .All(c=>(c.Attribute("name").Value == "a" && c.Attribute("value").Value=="1") || 
                    (c.Attribute("name").Value == "b" && c.Attribute("value").Value=="2")))
            .Select(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value);
```

Output

```
1 
4
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2:**
here's the LINQ based solution for this

```
 var nodes = document.Descendants("nodes").Descendants("node");

 return (from node in nodes
        let aSubNode = node.Descendants("subnode")
          .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "a" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value == "1")
        let bSubNode = node.Descendants("subnode")
          .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "b" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value == "2")
        where aSubNode != null && bSubNode != null
        select node.Attribute("id")?.Value).ToList();
```

**UPDATE 1:** 
I updated the code to read `id` attribute value from `node`element instead of `subnode`.

**ORIGINAL:** 
following isn't all LINQ but this should solve your problem

```
var nodes = document.Descendants("nodes").Descendants("node");

var ids=new List<string>();

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
       var aSubNode = node.Descendants("subnode")
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "a" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value == "1");
       var bSubNode=node.Descendants("subnode")
           .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "b" && a.Attribute("value")?.Value == "2");

       if (aSubNode==null || bSubNode==null)
           continue;
       ids.Add(node.Attribute("id")?.Value);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this returns me a list of 4 null strings. But thanks for your effort.

Comment: let me verify this

Comment: @PalleDue can you try now?, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that gives me the expected answer. I'm a little reluctant to accept it as the answer, though. It's not quite the elegant linq query I was looking for. I'll wait and see if a better solution comes up.

Comment: sure @PalleDue, I did try to go for all `LINQ` first, I'll try if I can convert this to `LINQ`

Comment: @PalleDue I've added the `LINQ` for this